# JavaScript Module Pattern - How to Create Sub Modules

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, module

How do I access/create a sub module based on the module pattern?

I would like to have the ability to access methods from sub modules in my Modules.js main file.

Module.js

```
var Module = (function() {

    function A(){
      console.log("Module: A");
      B();
    };

    function B(){
       console.log("Module: B");
       Module.Utils.C(); /* Here is the problem */
    };

    return {
      A:A,
      B:B
    }

} ());

$(function() {
    Module.A();
});
```

Module.Utils.js

```
var Module = Module ? Module : {};

Module.Utils = (function() {

    var settings = {
        x : 1,
        y : 2
    };

    function C(){
      console.log("Module.Utils: C");
    };

    function D(){
       console.log("Module.Utils: D");
    };

    return {
      C:C,
      D:D
    }

}());
```

Comment: I don't see how this would be a problem unless you invoke a main module function before defining the sub-module. You do however have a syntax error in module.utils.js. Typo?

Comment: the problem with this line `var Module = Module ? Module : {};` is that, if your submodule is loaded before the main module, the declaration of the main module will afterwards erase the declaration of the submodule, and no exception will be thrown.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your approach, provided:

- You load the sub-module script after the module script
- You do not attempt to access the sub-module script before it is loaded
- You're OK with making your primary module dependent on the existence of the sub-module. (I'm not so sure this is a good idea.)

#### Side-issue

Your code currently has a syntax error on the following line:

```
var Module.Utils = (function() {
```

There should be no `var` keyword preceding the assignment.

#### Example Code

Here's a simplified version of your code -- stripped to show only the methods I'm invoking -- that demonstrates that your approach works:

```
var Module = (function() {

    function B() {
        console.log("Module: B");
        Module.Utils.C(); /* accessing submodule public methods */
    };

    return {
        B: B
    };

})();

var Module = Module || {};

Module.Utils = (function() {

    function C() {
        console.log("Module.Utils: C");
    };

    return {
        C: C
    }

})();

Module.B();
```

Output:

```
Module: B
Module.Utils: C
```

Comment: The main question I have is: how to access function `C()` inside `Module` after `Module.Utils` is loaded?

Comment: regarding your third bullet point, that is, the issue with this line `var Module = Module ? Module : {};`, is that because, if the submodule is loaded before the main module, the declaration of the main module will afterwards erase the declaration of the submodule, without an exception to be thrown?

Comment: Ah, I see you use `Module.Utils.C();`, the module name, to access methods of the submodule `Utils`. Wouldn't keyword `this` also work?

Answer (score 3):

You should look into using an actual module framework like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/).

A "submodule" would then just be a module located at `module/utils`, and your `module` module would require it as a dependency, which RequireJS would take care of resolving for you.

Comment: I don't see how RequireJS would be beneficial.

Comment: Updated to explain... I thought it would be obvious.

Comment: Definitely helping me clean up my modules... and my entire project, and came with a whole bunch of other benefits.  Highly recommend looking into this and/or one of the other module loaders (CommonJs etc).  And to go even further you could integrate webpack (http://webpack.github.io/) which allows you to use any of the module loaders together in the same project.